# Double partial derivative at maximum or minimum points

Tags: calculus

Is this true?

Let $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ be open set, and $u:U \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable every order . If $x_0\in U$ is a maximum point of $u$, then

$$u_{x_i}(x)=0$$ and $$u_{x_ix_i}(x)<0.$$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not true, as the following simple example illustrates:

Take $U = R^1$, and let $f(x) = 1 - x^4$.  Then $f'(x) = -4x^3$; this function has a unique maximum at $x = 0$; but $f''(x) = -12x^2$, whence $f''(0) = 0$!

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Consider $n=1$ and take $u(x) = -x^4$...
Then $u''(0) = 0 = u'''(0) = u'(0)$. But
$$u^{(4)}(0) = -4! = -24 < 0$$
Generally for $n=1$, the first non-zero derivative will be of even order and less than $0$. More generally you have much uglier criterions, but that's not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $U$ is an open sets makes the "gradient equal to zero at the maximum" a *necessary* condition (if U was a closed set, then it would not be a necessary condition). The second derivative (Hessian) being negative (negative definite) is just a sufficient condition, so the condition might not hold, as the examples in the other answers have showed.

Comment: Could you tell me some example conditions that makes $u_{x_ix_i} \leq 0$ at the maximum point?

Comment: There cannot be conditions that turn a sufficient condition into a necessary condition. It runs the other way around: There are global characteristics of a function which guarantee that the second derivative will be smaller-equal to zero everywhere, and hence also at the maximum. If the function is concave in $U$, like $f(x) = -x^2 +cx$ for example.

Comment: That means if I change the conclusion to be $u_{x_ix_i}\leq 0$. This statement will be true?

Comment: Yes. It would then be a possible inflection point for the first derivative.